# Reading a .txt file in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fopen

I am trying to read a text file and display the contents to the screen. The file is just a list of words. I have placed the .txt file in the tree of my project but the code will not open it. My question is, is the .txt file in the wrong place? Is fopen the correct function to do this? I'm going round in circles with this and it seems so simple! :(

The file is stored in the directory under "ProjectName" -- Source Files -- File.txt

My code so far is:

```
int main (void)
{

char word [30];

    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("sort.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf( "File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);

        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        }

        fclose (fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Problem solved. I re-created a text file in my project by right clicking on Source Files then choosing Add New Item and choosing text file under the Utility option. I then copied my original text file data into it. The file was then created in the appropriate directory. Simple solution! Happy newbie-coder!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are opening a relative path, you need to have File.txt in the same folder as your .exe.  Of course, I'm assuming when you wrote File.txt, you meant sort.txt because that's what your code is referencing.

With managed languages, you have the ability to use "Copy Always" for any file, but with C++, you don't.  So to copy a specific file to the output directory, you'll need to add a Post-Build Event:

- Right click on the C++ project and select properties
- Expand 'Configuration Properties'
- Expand 'Build Events'
- Click on 'Post-Build Event'
- Paste `copy "$(ProjectDir)sort.txt" "$(OutputPath)"` into the 'Command Line' box
- Click 'Ok'

Now when you build, sort.txt should be copied to the same location as your executable.  Note that even though it looks like the sort.txt is in a 'Source Files' folder, it's really not (at least by default).

Comment: Thanks Andorbal, yes I did mean sort.txt! Both yourself and John T suggest the same solution which is good news. The bad news is I can't figure how to do it! When I right-click on the fle and choose properties I do not get any options for copying. All I see is a configuration wondow. Sorry to be a dumbass but I'm a newbie at this!

Comment: Are you right clicking through Visual Studio?  What configurations do you see?

Comment: Yes through VS. It shows general configuration properties and says the file is not excluded from the build and the item type as not participating in the build...

Comment: It doesn't work. It now fails on build with this error: 1>PostBuildEvent:
1>  '"I:\File Pointer\File Pointer\sort.txt"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command ""I:\File Pointer\File Pointer\sort.txt" "I:\File Pointer\Debug\"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 9009.
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: I didn't include 'copy' in the command you needed to paste.  Sorry!

Comment: Ok tried again, now I'm getting a different error... 1>  File Pointer.vcxproj -> I:\File Pointer\Debug\File Pointer.exe
1>PostBuildEvent:
1>  The specified path is invalid.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command ""copy I:\File Pointer\File Pointer\sort.txt" "I:\File Pointer\Debug\"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 161.
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: What's the actual path to sort.txt?

Comment: VS is looking for it in I:\File Pointer\File Pointer\sort.txt but the file is in C:\Users\FE\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File_Sort..... Maybe I should create the project in my local directory rather than on the server I directory...?

Comment: Just replace $(ProjectDir)sort.txt with the actual path; I just assumed it was in the project dir.

Comment: no good the whole project has stopped working now, it won't do anything. I think I'll have to start again and try to somehow get my file onto the directory on the server. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be compiled into the bin folder within your solution. The file open is looking for the file in the same place as the .exe, within the bin folder. If you click the file in the Solution Folder, right click and choose Properties, then set the option "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always", VS will copy that file to the same place as the exe.